# update a int in every month in java

Tags: java

I want to update int at starts of a new month. If I login first time of new month, I want to update that int on my database(oracle 11g release II). Is it possible with java? and how can I do it?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Yes, but have you tried anything?

Comment: Many things are possible with Java unless you don't try it.

Comment: Whatever problem you're trying to solve, this seems like an *extremely* fragile way to solve it. If you instead posted the real question, you might find better ways to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

It is very possible, the easiest idea would be to have two fields in the database. One with your int value and anotherone with a timestamp (if it´s Oracle, a plain Date). On the Date you save the last Date when the int was updated and each time the user logs in, you can check if the current month is different from the one stored in the Database.

However, in this case it would be better if you asked for the purpose of the solution you want to implement, maybe there´s a simpler idea.

Regards